# Google Play Console приложение отклонено

Tags: google-play-console

Я добавил приложение в Google Play Console.
Статус приложения был пару дней - "Готовится к публикации".
Затем статус сменился на - "Отклонено".
Сделав что писалось в письме и нажав Отправить на повторную проверку, статус приложения так и стался  - "Отклонено".
Должен ли меняться статус в подобной ситуации, если нет то как я узнаю что приложение не прошло повторной проверки и оно снова отклонено?

Comment: На почту никаких писем не приходило?

Answer (score 0):

В письме пришедшим на почту Google указывает , что вам необходимо предпринять для исправления ситуации, а также причину по которой отклонил приложение. А так, конечно же нет.Это говорит о том, что вы исправили что-то неверно/ не до конца / исправили не то и тдтп.

Comment: А вопрос читал?